# How to set a prop from a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new with react, I know it's a nub question but I don't know how to resolve it.

I need to make more than one heart button and change the prop `paramether` who I labeled `isChecked` to `true` or `false`, so the button will change from `HeartNormal` to `HeartFull`.

The code can't have a state to do this cause every button need change between `HeartNormal` and `HeartFull` separately.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends Component {
    handleLike = props =>{
        props.isCheck = true;
    }
    renderer(){
        return(
            <div>
            <Heart isClicked={false} onClick={() => this.handleLike(this.props)}/>
            <Heart isClicked={false} onClick={() => this.handleLike(this.props)}/>
            <Heart isClicked={false} onClick={() => this.handleLike(this.props)}/>
            <Heart isClicked={false} onClick={() => this.handleLike(this.props)}/>
            <Heart isClicked={false} onClick={() => this.handleLike(this.props)}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
function Heart(props){
    const isClicked = props.isClicked;
    if(isClicked){
        return <button onClick={props.onClick}><i className="fas fa-heart"></i></button>
    }else{
        return <button onClick={props.onClick}><i className="far fa-heart"></i></button>
    }
}
export default Test;
```

In the `handleLike`, There are another parameters to invite the id off the post liked to the node server, cause that this is the ideal structure to make the code for me. I hope somebody can help me to fix this.

Comment: Does Test need to know anything about the state of the Heart component? Like what happens if I click the third Heart - should Hearts 1 & 2 also be toggled? And if so, which one should send the info to your node server?

Comment: Every button need be changed separatelly. That code was just to test the changed beetwen the Heart Normal and Heart Full. Basically the code get the id from the post and send on a url like this "localhost:3000/posts/5d194d2db9ec4dbb68b13145/like" using an method  POST the node server get the id from the url and add an like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make Heart a component with state, then every hearts you have will have states separately and render differently

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends Component {
//should be render
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
              <Heart isClicked={false} />
              <Heart isClicked={false} />
              <Heart isClicked={false} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Heart extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            clicked: this.props.isClicked
        }
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})
    }

    render(){
        const {clicked} = this.state
        return(<button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
                <i className={clicked ? "fas fa-heart" : "far fa-heart"}></i>
               </button>)
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**: You can't assign to props in React because they are read only. The way you update props is to update the value that the parent sends to this component. 
 Meaning `<Test isCheck={/* change the value here */} />`

**Solution**: you can use a state for each individual `Heart` component by using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html). This way, each `Heart` will have a separate state, independent of each other, and the `Test` component won't need to keep track of each state.

Here is the updated code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends Component {
    renderer(){
        return(
            <div>
            <Heart/>
            <Heart/>
            <Heart/>
            <Heart/>
            <Heart/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
function Heart(props){
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);

    return (
        <button onClick={() -> setIsClicked(true)}>
            <i className={clicked ? "fas fa-heart" : "far fa-heart"}></i>
        </button>
    );
}
export default Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use state here. What you can do is store an array in your `Test` component's `state` that represents each heart, then mutate them individually.

It would look something like this:

```
class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      hearts: [
        { liked: false },
        { liked: false },
        { liked: false },
        { liked: false },
        { liked: false }
      ]
    };
  }

  handleHeartClick(heartIndex) {
    let clickedHeart;

    this.setState({
      hearts: this.state.hearts.map((heart, index) => {
        if (index === heartIndex) {
          heart.isCheck = !heart.isCheck;
          clickedHeart = heart;
        }

        return heart;
      });
    });

    // Send your clickedHeart off to your node server, or whatever else you need with it
  }

  render() {
    const heartComponents = this.state.hearts.map((heart, index) => (
      <Heart isClicked={heart.isCheck} onClick={() => this.handleHeartClick(index)} />
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        {heartComponents}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The other answers are good, especially Brandon's use of [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), however this one keeps your data logic in the container and keeps your presentational component simple.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct if the hearts don't need to know anything about each other, but I don't think that's your case. If I click the third heart, you probably also want #1 and #2 to fill in. In which case, your state should be taken *out* of the Heart component and moved up to the Test component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

const Test = () => {
  // How many hearts do you want to show?
  const numberOfHearts = 5

  // Start with no hearts filled in
  const [likeValue, setLikeValue] = useState(0)

  const handleClick = (heartValue) => {
    setLikeValue(heartValue)
    // Update your database with the new value of likes
  }

  // Loop to show as many hearts as you set above
  const hearts = [...Array(numberOfHearts).keys()].map((v) => {
    // v is 0 for the first, 1 for the second, etc
    return (
      <Heart
        isLiked={likeValue > v}
        key={v}
        heartValue={v + 1}
        handleClick={handleClick}
      />
    )
  })

  return <div>{hearts}</div>
}

const Heart = ({ handleClick, heartValue, isLiked }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => handleClick(heartValue)}>
      <i className={isLiked ? "fas fa-heart" : "far fa-heart"} />
    </button>
  )
}
```

When you click the third heart, #1, #2, and #3 will be "liked", #4 and #5 will not. So the other solutions work if you want to click #3 and only have the third heart filled in, but if this is more like a rating system, you should lift the state up and manage it at the parent (Test) component level.